# How to set a global environmental variables using Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a sample make file with this entry

```
.PHONY: test
test:
    @export DD="test-variable"
```

When i run `make test` from my terminal, i want to be able to run `echo $DD` and have it output `test-variable` to my screen in my terminal session. But this doesn't work, as i understand Makefile only set env variables for only sub processes. But is there a way to make this work?

Comment: No, there is no way allow `make`, or any other process, to modify its parent's environment without the cooperation of the parent.

Comment: Not entirely. But insightful. Now the question is how do i do IPC between the Makefile process and the parent process.

Comment: If the parent is the shell, a simple and obvious solution is `dd=$(make -s test-expr)` and have `test-expr` output the value. Tangentially, don't use upper case for your private variables.

Comment: If you now have a different question, then you could consider posing it as a new, separate SO question.

Comment: You could also consider whether `make` is really the right tool for the job you're trying to do.